# How to configure ppolicy overlays in Openldap 2.4.28 Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, openldap, password-policy

I am working with OpenLDAP with slapd 2.4.28, it has no slapd.conf file in the /etc/ldap/ folder. Most of the tutorials and videos I went through are on the configuring of slapd.conf.

Has anyone tried in the slapd 2.4.28 in ubuntu 12.04 server?

Following the steps were performed but its not working for me:

```
#ldapadd -Q -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi://ldap.technology.com -f /etc/ldap/schema/ppolicy.ldif 


  #ldapmodify -Q -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi://ldap.technology.com
    dn: cn=module{0},cn=config
    changetype: modify
    add: olcModuleLoad
    olcModuleLoad: ppolicy.la


#ldapadd -W -D "cn=admin,dc=technology,dc=com"
    dn: ou=Policies,dc=technology,dc=com
    objectClass: organizationalUnit
    objectClass: top
    ou: Policies

# ldapadd -W -D "cn=admin,dc=technology,dc=com"
    dn: cn=default,ou=Policies,dc=technology,dc=com
    objectClass: top
    objectClass: device
    objectClass: pwdPolicy
    cn: default
    pwdAttribute: 2.5.4.35
    pwdMaxAge: 15552000
    pwdInHistory: 3
    pwdMinLength: 6
    pwdMaxFailure: 4
    pwdLockout: TRUE
    pwdLockoutDuration: 1800
    pwdGraceAuthNLimit: 3
    pwdMustChange: TRUE
    pwdAllowUserChange: TRUE
    pwdSafeModify: TRUE

# ldapadd -Q -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi://ldap.technology.com
    dn: olcOverlay=ppolicy,olcDatabase={1}hdb,cn=config
    objectClass: olcOverlayConfig
    objectClass: olcPPolicyConfig
    olcOverlay: ppolicy
    olcPPolicyDefault: cn=default,ou=Policies,dc=technology,dc=com
    olcPPolicyHashCleartext: TRUE
    olcPPolicyUseLockout: TRUE
```

All I am being able to do is to assign the pwdpolicy object to the users groups and organisation unit but none of it is taking any effect, just a default password policy taking an effect.

Comment: What does 'assign the pwdpolicy object to the users groups and organisation unit' mean?

Comment: I meant, i can assign pwdpolicy to the specific user like cn=mark adam,dc=technology,dc=com. but the password policy is not taking any effect not even to the specific user (mark), i did it also thought the use of phpldapadmin/ apache directory studio without any error but the policy is not taking any effects.
thank you.

Comment: Are you using the change password extended operation? If you don't, the password policy has no effect.

Comment: i dont think i am using the change password extended operation. Can u guide me on how to use the change password extended operation? I googled on the matter of extended operation and i havent found anything useful till date. thank for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

you should define a new policy entry and add a pwdPolicySubentry point to the new defined policy(like this pwdPolicySubentry=cn=mypolicy,ou=policies,dc=test,dc=com) to the user you want to use new policy rather than default policy.

Comment: apart from all the problem, currently i cant even being able to put changed default password policy into effect. I mean, i can change the minimum password length to be 12 characters in the default password setting but its not taking effect. Can you explain a little bit more regarding your solution? thanks